# Check the order of images inside div using sortable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I have images inside div and I am using sortable plugin on jquery to drag and drop the arrangement of images. I just need to figure out the number arrangement of images even when i drag and drop it off.
For example I drag test2.jpg in front of test1.jpg. So the arrangement should be `1. test2.jpg, 2. test1.jpg, 3. test3.jpg.`

html

```
<div id="sortable">
    <img id="product_preview" class="ui-state-default" src="/images/test1.jpg">
    <img id="product_preview" class="ui-state-default" src="/images/test2.jpg">
    <img id="product_preview" class="ui-state-default" src="/images/test3.jpg">
<div>
```

javascript

```
$( function() {
   $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
   $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
} );
```

Comment: ```$( ".selector" ).sortable({
  sort: function( event, ui ) {}
});``` This should help.

Comment: You have an issue with the IDs for each. They must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want top use `serialize` or `toArray` to gather this detail. You will want to ensure that the ID is correct for each item.

> Note: If serialize returns an empty string, make sure the id attributes include an underscore. They must be in the form: `"set_number"` For example, a 3 element list with id attributes `"foo_1"`, `"foo_5"`, `"foo_2"` will serialize to `"foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2"`. You can use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and number. For example `"foo=1"`, `"foo-1"`, and `"foo_1"` all serialize to `"foo[]=1"`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var sorted = $(this).sortable("serialize");
      var sortedIDs = $(this).sortable("toArray");
      console.log(sorted, sortedIDs);
    }
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="sortable">
  <img id="product_1" class="ui-state-default" src="/images/test1.jpg" />
  <img id="product_2" class="ui-state-default" src="/images/test2.jpg" />
  <img id="product_3" class="ui-state-default" src="/images/test3.jpg" />
<div>
```

See More:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize
- https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray